# adding an image to a cell in phpexcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm creating a product list in excel, that contains a row for each product, with a title, description and an image.

The title, description and price are all being added correctly, but the image is not, the products are added in a loop, but the image is not rendering correctly according to the index. My code is:

```
    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

    $products = $this->getProducts();

    foreach ($products as $i => $product) {
        $price = get_post_meta($product->ID, 'wpcf-prijs');
        $subcategoryId = wp_get_post_categories($product->ID)[0];
        $subCategory = get_category($subcategoryId);
        $mainCategory = get_category($subCategory->category_parent);

        $logo = types_render_field('afbeelding',
                            ['width' => 200, 'output' => 'raw', 'post_id' => $product->ID]);

        $logo = get_home_path() . str_replace(home_url() . '/', '', $logo);


        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A' . $i, $product->ID);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C' . $i, $product->post_title);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D' . $i,
                            strip_tags(types_render_field('omschrijving', array('post_id' => $product->ID))));
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('E' . $i, $price);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('E' . $i)->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('F' . $i, $subCategory->name);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('G' . $i, $mainCategory->name);

        //Add the image to the cell
        $objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing();
        $objDrawing->setName('Logo ' . $i);
        $objDrawing->setDescription('Logo ' . $i);
        $objDrawing->setPath($logo);
        $objDrawing->setResizeProportional(true);
        $objDrawing->setWidth(40);
        $objDrawing->setCoordinates('B' . $i);
        $objDrawing->setWorksheet($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet());
    }

    $objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
    $objWriter->save(str_replace('productExporter.php', 'products.xlsx', __FILE__));
```

The result looks like this:

[image: product list]

As you can see, the first 5 items are added to the first row, then the next 3 items are added to the second 3 and the last 2 items are added to the third row, instead of 1 image in each row. Does anyone have any idea, what the reason is for this behavior?